# What effect does hydrogen bonding have on H NMR spectra?

Tags: experimental-chemistry, nmr-spectroscopy

My thinking is that an increase in electron density caused by hydrogen bonding should cause the chemical shift of participating atoms to be moved downfield. Am I right or wrong?

Can someone provide an example showing this phenomenon?

Comment: Related: [Is there intramolecular hydrogen bonding in salicylaldehyde?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/75155/16683) (It doesn't quite sound related, but there's an NMR spectrum there.)

Comment: There is also scalar J-coupling between the hydrogen and the acceptor atom, [source](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/11460545)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hydrogen bonding is well known to cause large changes in chemical shift values– this is evident if you look up the chemical shift of an alcohol in a data-book (for an aliphatic alcohol this is anywhere between 0.5 and ca. 6.0 ppm depending on solvent/concentration), where a large range of values are given.<sup>[1]</sup>

In general,  formation of hydrogen bonds causes shifts to move to a higher frequency (higher ppm) due to deshielding.<sup>[2]</sup> In itself this is counter-intuitive, as in a hydrogen bonding interaction the H is actually *receiving* electron density from the donor atom (and therefore should be shielded). In the case of NMR however, the *actual* electron density isn’t whats causing this, but rather the field set up from the presence of the interaction.<sup>[#]</sup>

**Intramolecular vs intermolecular hydrogen bonding**

Although hydrogen bonding *does* cause a change in chemical shift, it is often only evident (/causes an issue) with *inter*molecular hydrogen bonding (between two molecules). With *intra*molecular bonding, the system is sufficiently stable that the chemical shift of the proton is consistent (and doesn't change with concentration/solvent, much).

To give an example,<sup>[##]</sup> consider the 1H-NMR of methanol and hexafluoroacetylacetone:<sup>[3]</sup>

[image]

On the top is the spectra of the neat compounds, where hydrogen bonding is present. On the bottom, the spectra of the compounds with added tetrachloromethane (which breaks down hydrogen bonding). Whilst the intramolecular hydrogen bonding in hexafluoroacetylacetone is unchanged, we can see immediately that the chemical shift of the hydroxyl proton to move.

**Applications**

Hydrogen bonding in NMR may seem rather inconvenient (and indeed it can be in routine structure elucidation work where the shift keeps on moving depending on how dry the NMR solvent is on any given day), however it has played a vital role in biochemistry and supramolecular chemistry, where the change in proton shifts can be used to determine whether or not multiple components are interacting.

A classic example is the interaction between cytosine and guanidine (C pairs with G in DNA via a hydrogen bonding interaction), which can be observed by NMR when the two compounds are mixed in an equimolar ratio:

[image]

<sup>[1]: Presch, E.; Buhlmann, P.; Badertscher, M. *Structure Determination of Organic Compounds- Tables of Spectral Data*; Springer: Berlin, 2009</sup>

<sup>[2]: Günther, H. *NMR Spectroscopy- Basic Principles, Concepts, and Applications in Chemistry*; Wiley: Weinheim, 2013</sup>

<sup>[#]: This is covered in *Spin Dynamics* by Levitt if you have any interest in the theoretical reasoning behind this</sup>

<sup>[##]: In [this](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/75159/21296) other answer, i’d previously given the example of salicaldehyde, which shows a consistent intramolecular H-bond free from solvent/concentration effects</sup>

<sup>[3]: *Figure reproduced from* Breitmaier, E. *Structure Elucidation by NMR in Organic Chemistry*; Wiley: Chichester, 2002</sup>